# How to count specific values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have below query that give my the next results (below).

I would like to know how can I count the "MIR_ID" that appears more than once only from query results (if it possible).

Thanks!

My query:

```
with Source as (
select 
request_id
,description
,substring(VwDurationIndicator.RequestDetails, 5, 6) as Mir_ID
, request_type

from vortex_hvc.dbo.VwDurationIndicator 
 left join 
 vw_public_request_material_location_mir 
 on substring(VwDurationIndicator.RequestDetails, 5, 6) like vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id
where DateDiff(hour, CreatedTime, getdate()) < 9 and
 request_type = 'MIR' and SITE = 'HVC' 

        )
 select Source.*

 ,count(Mir_ID) as total
 from Source

 group by Mir_ID,request_id,description,request_type

 order by request_id
```

Query return:

```
request_id  description Mir_ID  request_type    total
152788  VPO: Y7363040RS, Step: PPV-M, Bin: BIN 01   335403  MIR 2
152788  VPO: Y7242580, Step: PPV-S FUSE, Bin: BIN 01    335403  MIR 1
152788  VPO: Y7243570, Step: PPV-S, Bin: BIN 01 335403  MIR 1
152788  VPO: Y7243580, Step: PPV-S, Bin: BIN 01 335403  MIR 1
152788  VPO: Y7322650, Step: PPV, Bin: BIN 01   335403  MIR 5
152788  VPO: Y7363020, Step: PPV-M, Bin: BIN 01 335403  MIR 2
152791  VPO: Y7324440, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152791  VPO: Y7324550, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152791  VPO: Y7324480, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 2
152791  VPO: Y7324590, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152791  VPO: Y7324540, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152791  VPO: Y7324580, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 3
152791  VPO: Y7324430, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152791  VPO: Y7324660, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152791  VPO: Y7324470, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335412  MIR 1
152792  VPO: Y7342740, Step: PRODUCTION BURN-IN, Bin: BIN 01    335419  MIR 1
152792  VPO: Y7342730, Step: PRODUCTION BURN-IN, Bin: BIN 01    335419  MIR 1
152794  VPO: Y7324480, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335420  MIR 1
152794  VPO: Y7324540, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335420  MIR 1
152794  VPO: Y7324420, Step: OLB, Bin: BIN 2571 335420  MIR 2
```

Comment: By using COUNT????

Comment: if you have others ideas you're more than welcome :)

Comment: What would really help is some ddl, sample data and the desired output for that sample data. From the gibberish posted above it is impossible to tell what is in what column. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT MIR_ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_MIR_ID
FROM YOUR_RESULT
GROUP BY MIR_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Assuming `YOUR_RESULT` contains the result you provided in the post. You can either store your result in a table OR use this query outside your original query.

Comment: hi,
I have checked it but query retunes no values after executing.

Comment: What are possible values of `MIR_ID`? I am not able to figure out from your post.

Comment: my mistake it return values but not counting according to MIR_ID.

Comment: Are you storing the results in a table before running the `COUNT(*)`? If so, try verifying the table contains the results as expected.

Comment: only numbers... for example after query executing I want to see that MIR_ID "335403" appears 5 times and like this for all others MIR_ID numbers.

Comment: What is the count you are getting for `MIR_ID` 335403?

Comment: Its appears at 3 different rows, one of them has 2, 2nd has 5 and the last have 2 ( in my original results this Mir_id appears 6 times so this is the number I want to get)